# R resources for GMM estimation and testing of multifactor asset pricing models

Tags: programming, factor-models, estimation, gmm

Has anyone seen R script for GMM estimation and testing of asset pricing models such as Fama-French 3-factor or similar? Ideally, I would like to have R scripts corresponding to Cochrane "Asset Pricing" (2005) chapter 12 and related chapters.

Now, I have looked around and found some bits for the CAPM (including in the [GMM package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/vignettes/gmm_with_R.pdf)) and some roughly equivalent bits elsewhere but not much else, and nothing for multifactor models. Perhaps R is not popular in the field of asset pricing, or perhaps I looked in the wrong places, I do not know. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Being unsure if this is on topic, I posted this on the site's [general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129199/quant-se-general-chat) 4 days ago, but got no response. I then posted it on Meta but got directed to post it here instead (and have deleted the Meta post already).

Comment: The post got a couple of close votes regarding details and clarity. I would appreciate some constructive comments to substantiate these votes and help me improve the post. What is unclear about seeking R code for testing Fama-French 3-factor model or its brothers (Carhart 4-factor, Fama-French 5-factor and the like)? This is standard textbook material, and I refer to a specific textbook (Cochrane, 2005) as an example.

Comment: I agree with Richard here. For me the question is clear. Related chapters might make it a bit more vague than necessary but on the other hand: I don't think there is a repo anywhere that just does chapter 12 and not other relevant chapters.

Comment: @BobJansen, that makes sense. The chapter(s) of Cochrane (2005) is just meant as an illustration.

Comment: Does it have to be `R` code or would another language or pseudo code/instructions suffice?

Comment: @Kevin, I am looking for R code. I have some idea of what pseudocode would be, but I fear the actual coding might take a long time to get right. Yet if you have something in non-R you find helpful, you could definitely share a link in a comment.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't have some link but I could write up some code (probably in matlab which I use most often) if that's alright? Might be able to translate it to R (they're quite similar, I find).

Comment: @Kevin, it depends on how much time you have to spare. If you can help me (and those coming in my footsteps) with Matlab code, I would surely appreciate that. I am not sure how easy the transition between Matlab and R will be, though. I think I could easily spend a full working day trying to figure out how exactly to code some simple thing. Without great examples, I would have to dig into the source codes behind R functions, and you probably know / can guess how time consuming that might be. And I am not a fast coder. Realistically, I was looking at a full week of work if I start from scratch.

Comment: (@Kevin, in the one-week estimate, I include not only plain estimation but also some testing and some playing with the choice of a weighting matrix to see how that affects the results.)

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, I provide Matlab code for implementing a two-step GMM test of a multi-factor asset pricing model. I closely follow [Cochrane (2005)](https://www.johnhcochrane.com/asset-pricing) which is an amazig book. See also this [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZPk51Uniuc). The code begins from uploading the data and goes on to perform the GMM, calculate $t$-statistics and conduct the $J$-test. I hope it's easy enough to translate the code below to most other languages.

## Upload the data

This first step is simple and just about uploading data from [Ken French's website](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html). For this example, I use the Fama-French five-factor model and the 25 portfolios sorted on size and book/market as test assets. My sample is July 1963 - June 2023.

```
clearvars                   % clear workspace
close all                   % close all windows
clc                         % clear command window

%%
% Upload raw data from Ken's website
TestAssets = readmatrix('25_Portfolios_5x5');                % 721 x 26 array
Factors = readmatrix('F-F_Research_Data_5_Factors_2x3');     % 721 x 7 array

% flip dimensions
TestAssets = TestAssets';
Factors = Factors';

% drop first row which would contain year/month
Factors(1,:) = [];          
TestAssets(1,:) = [];

% drop first column which would contain portfolio names
Factors(:,1) = [];          
TestAssets(:,1) = [];

% extract risk-free rate from factor file
Rf = Factors(end,:);
Factors(end,:) = [];

%Number of months, test assets and factors:
[N,T] = size(TestAssets);
[K,~] = size(Factors);

%Calculate excess returns
Rf = Rf/100;
Factors = Factors/100;
TestAssets = TestAssets/100 - Rf;
```

Note that $T=720$, $K=5$, and $N=25$. To check that everything looks alright, let's plot the average returns of our test assets

```
AvgRet = mean(TestAssets,2)*100;  % time series average 
AvgRet = reshape(AvgRet,[5,5]);
bar3(AvgRet)
xlabel('size')
ylabel('value')
zlabel('mean mo return %')
```

The result looks like this and indicates a positive value premium (amongst small stocks).
[image]

## Do the GMM test

Let's turn to the fun bit. I implement the closed-form solution from Cochrane (2005) and follow his notation. In particular, see sections 10.1 and 13.2.

```
d = 1/T*TestAssets*Factors';
ERe = mean(TestAssets,2);
I = eye(N);  % identity matrix
% first step
    b_1 = inv(d'*d)*d'*ERe;
    SDF_1 = 1-b_1'*Factors;
    Errors_1 = SDF_1.*TestAssets;  % pricing errors of our model
    S_1 = cov(Errors_1'); % you can use fancier methods here (see section 11.7)
    W_1 = inv(S_1);   % weighting matrix for next step
    g_1 = mean(Errors_1,2); % average pricing errors (our moment conditions)
    cov_b_1 = 1/T*inv(d'*d)*d'*S_1*d*inv(d'*d);
    cov_g_1 = 1/T * (I-d*inv(d'*d)*d')*S_1*(I-d*inv(d'*d)*d');
    tstat_b_1 = b_1./diag(sqrt(cov_b_1));
% second step    
    b_2 = inv(d'*W_1*d)*d'*W_1*ERe;
    SDF_2 = 1-b_2'*Factors;
    Errors_2 = SDF_2.*TestAssets;
    S_2 = cov(Errors_2'); % you can use fancier methods here (see section 11.7)
    g_2 = mean(Errors_2,2);
    cov_b_2 = 1/T*inv(d'*inv(S_2)*d);
    cov_g_2 = 1/T * (S_2 - d*inv(d'*inv(S_2)*d)*d');
    tstat_b_2 = b_2./diag(sqrt(cov_b_2));
    J_2 = T*g_2'*inv(S_2)*g_2; %J-test statistic for overidentifying restrictions 
    J_crit_value = chi2inv(0.95,N-K); %H0: model is correct (all moments are zero)
    % reject H0 if J_2 > J_crit_value (ie the model doesn't price the test assets)
```

For example, the point estimate for SMB is 5.40 ($t$-statistic: 3.56). The $J$ test is rejected, however, suggesting that the model doesn't price the 25 portfolios (btw: the test is a really high hurdle and rarely passed).

## Notes

$d$ is simply a second-moment matrix ($d = \mathbb{E}[R^e  f] = \mathbb{C}\text{ov}(R^e,f)+\mathbb{E}[R^e]\mathbb{E}[f]$)

```
MyCov = NaN(N,K);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:K
        temp =  cov(TestAssets(i,:),Factors(j,:),1);
        MyCov(i,j) = temp(1,2)+mean(TestAssets(i,:))*mean(Factors(j,:));
    end
end
%compare d with MyCov!
```

We can implement a **Do-it-Yourself GMM**. Suppose we're not as clever as Cochrane (or Hansen) and do not know how to find the above closed-form solution. We can still use a naive brute-force approach to perform GMM. The aim is simply to minimise the pricing errors from our model. The objective function is $g(b)'Wg(b)$. The matlab code is

```
    W = eye(N);
    SDF = @(b) 1-b'*Factors;
    Errors = @(b) SDF(b).*TestAssets;
    g = @(b) mean(Errors(b),2);
    ObjFun = @(b) g(b)'*W* g(b);
    my_b_1 = fminsearch(ObjFun,ones(K,1));
    % compare my_b_1 with b_1 from the closed-form solution.
```

More notes. It's easy to compare different factor models using GMM (see Section 13.3 in Cochrane's textbook). Note that the standard errors from the above code are a tiny bit off because I do not correct for the fact that the factor mean is estimated from the same sample. Cochrane writes himself: *In my experience so far with this method, the correction for the fact that $Ef$ is estimated is very small in practice, so that little damage is done in ignoring it (as is the case with the Shanken correction).* So I kept it simple. He does explain how to fix the standard errors though (pages 257/258).

Comment: This will take me time to digest, but the bounty is yours :)

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you. Please let me know if you have questions

Comment: @RichardHardy Hi there! Just wanted to briefly ask if you ever had a chance to look at it and whether it makes sense to you, Richard? Or is the code answering your question?

Comment: Sorry! This got burried under more urgent items. I intend to return to this later. I appreciate your help!